# Is it possible to parse a Map<String, List<MyObject>> in Yaml for java Dropwizard

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, dropwizard

I have an issue where I'm trying to parse a yaml file using a `Map<String, Pin>` but Dropwizard keeps complaining that its unable to parse it.

My Yaml file looks like this -

```
us:
  baseUrl: https://www.example.com
  fixture1: https://www.example.com/fixture1
  fixture2: https://www.example.com/fixture2
  filters:
    pins:
      fixture1:
        - category: test_category1
            urls:
                - url: https://www.example.com/fixture1/test
                  name: fixture1 entry
                  weight: 1000

      fixture2:
        - category: test_category_2
            urls:
                - url: https://www.example.com/fixture2/test
                  name: fixture2 entry
                  weight: 1000
```

Im using Jackson to parse it with code

```
    try {
        Map<String, Country> countries = mapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream(COUNTRY_CONFIG_FILE),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Country>>() {
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CrossLinkerException("Country config is null");
    }
```

The Country object is a pojo that has the following properties

```
public class Country {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String goodsUrl;
    private String localUrl;
    private TestFilter filters;
}
class TestFilter {
    private Map<String, List<Pin>> pins;
}
public class Pin {
    private String category;
    private List<Link> urls;
}
public class Link {
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private Float weight;
}
```

When I start up the application it fails with error Country config is null.

Comment: print full stacktrace. `(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CrossLinkerException("Country config is null");
    }` and post with your question.

Comment: Looks like the file couldn't be found. Make sure to include the `IOException` as cause of your custom exception to see more details of the real issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza file is found because I I try a different configuration it will work.

Comment: Well, then there's an issue parsing the file. Again, include the IOException and log the whole exception stack trace to see what's the real issue.